# Anyway to make jenkins build every exists commits?

Tags: git, jenkins, build

I'm trying to find a way to build every exists commits when adding new project to my jenkins.
For example:
I already created a project [here](https://jenkins.zxda.net/job/Genisys/) 
Some of my users request me to build old versions(commits) so they can use them,it's imposslble for me to checkout every commit and perform a manually build.
I want to build every old commits [here](https://github.com/iTXTech/Genisys/commits/master) automatically when I add this project to my jenkins.
Is there anyway to do that?Deleting and re-createing the jenkins project is acceptable.

PS:Tried to search on Google,but it seems that there's nobody have such a demand...(or I just typed wrong keywords?)

Answer (score 1):

You need first to script that process: once it is scripted, you can call that same script from Jenkins.

The script would need to list all commits, and determine if there is a build or not. Typically, you would leave a marker on the commit to indicate that a build was performed: a tag, or (more discrete) a [`git notes`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-notes)

That way, you can run/interrupt/restart that script as many time as you want: for any commit it detects there is no build, it can trigger one (`git checkout + build`)

Executed in context of a Jenkins job, the git checkout would set the working tree to the right commit, launch a build, publish its result (the binary artifact) somewhere, then tag or annotate the commit.